# Java homework: using an equals method with an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, object, equals

I have created an array of Song objects.  A song contains the variables title, author, interpreter, (int)yearReleased, album, and fileName.  I am using a main method to test my array of songs and my equals method.  The test is supposed to fill an array with five song objects and use my equals method to ensure the new entry is not a duplicate of a previous entry.  My test class compiles, but when I enter duplicate song information I keep getting an error.  If anyone could give me a tip or point me in the correct direction I would greatly appreciate it.  Any other tips would also be great.  As a student, it is great to hear good real world advice from professionals.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Test{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);

    Song[] songTest = new Song[5];
    boolean match;
    int count = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter 5 songs\n");

    for(Song x:songTest)
    {
        do{
            match = false;
            x = new Song();
            System.out.print("Title: ");
            x.setTitle(kybd.nextLine());
            System.out.print("Author: ");
            x.setAuthor(kybd.nextLine());
            System.out.print("Interpreter: ");
            x.setInterpreter(kybd.nextLine());
            System.out.print("Year released: ");
            x.setYearReleased(kybd.nextInt());
            kybd.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Album: ");
            x.setAlbum(kybd.nextLine());
            System.out.print("File name: ");
            x.setFileName(kybd.nextLine());
            System.out.print(x);
            System.out.println();
            for(int i = 0; i<count; i++)
                if(songTest[i].equals(x)){
                    match = true;
                    System.out.print("Duplicate");
                }
        }while(match);
        count++;
    }
}
}




public class Song
{
public String title;
public String author;
public String interpreter;
public int yearReleased;
public String album;
public String fileName;

//private vars
private int reviewScore = 0;
private int reviews = 0;
private double average;

//Mutator methods

public void setTitle(String t)
{
    this.title = t;
}

public void setAuthor(String a)
{
    this.author = a;
}

public void setInterpreter(String i)
{
    this.interpreter = i;
}

public void setYearReleased(int y)
{
    if (y>0)
        this.yearReleased = y;
    else
    {
        System.out.print ("This song is not that old");
        this.yearReleased = -5;
    }
}

public void setAlbum(String a)
{
    this.album = a;
}

public void setFileName(String f)
{
    this.fileName = f;
}

public void addReviewScore(int s)
{
    if (s>0 && s<6)
    {
        this.reviewScore += s;
        this.reviews++;
    }
    else
        System.out.print("This is not a valid review score!");
}

//Accessor methods

public String getTitle()
{
    return this.title;
}

public String getAuthor()
{
    return this.author;
}

public String getInterpreter()
{
    return this.interpreter;
}

public int getYearReleased()
{
    return this.yearReleased;
}

public String getAlbum()
{
    return this.album;
}

public String getFileName()
{
    return this.fileName;
}

public double getAverage()
{
    this.average = this.calculateAverage();
    return this.average;
}

//Methods

public boolean equals(Song otherSong)
{
    boolean isEqual = false;
    //compare this song to the otherSong
    isEqual =
        this.title == otherSong.title &&
        this.author == otherSong.author &&
        this.interpreter == otherSong.interpreter &&
        this.yearReleased == otherSong.yearReleased &&
        this.album == otherSong.album &&
        this.fileName == otherSong.fileName;
    return isEqual;
}
public String toString()
{
    String songInfo;
    songInfo = 
        "***Song information***\n" +
        "Title: " + this.title + 
        "\nAuthor: " + this.author +
        "\nInterpreter: " + this.interpreter +
        "\nYear Released: " + this.yearReleased +
        "\nAlbum: " + this.album +
        "\nFile name: " + this.fileName +
        "\nYears old: " + this.yearsOld(); 
    return songInfo;
}

public int yearsOld()
{
    int yearsOld = (2012 - this.yearReleased);
    return yearsOld;
}

//Private methods
private double calculateAverage()
{
    this.average = ((double)this.reviewScore/(double)this.reviews);
    return this.average;

}
```

}

Comment: "I keep getting an error".  When something doesn't work as you expect, always fully describe what you expect and what the actual result was, and/or provide a stack trace when an "error happens".

Comment: For `String` comparisons, you should always use `equals()` method to compare values of two strings and not `==`. `==` compares if two string objects point to the same memory location. `equals()` does actual value comparison.

Comment: Are you sure you know what's the correct way to compare Strings?  Your equals method seems problematic to me.  Have a brief search in Google or StackOverflow on "Java String Comparison"

Comment: FYI, if you use netbeans IDE, it automatically generates a prototype for an equals method for you. but the whole point of this exercise is to learn how to do it.

Comment: If you override *equals()*, make sure you follow the **hashcode contract**.

Comment: Note that the [homework] tag is obsolete.

Comment: To the comment by gotuskar, double check your equals method in the Song class. You are performing String comparisons using == (which is not what you intend). You should use equals() to compare Strings.

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code and reproduced the error which occurs at this line:

```
                if(songTest[i].equals(x)){
```

rewriting your equals method (or getting eclipse to do it for me) and adding the hashCode() solved the problem:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((album == null) ? 0 : album.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((author == null) ? 0 : author.hashCode());
    long temp;
    temp = Double.doubleToLongBits(average);
    result = prime * result + (int) (temp ^ (temp >>> 32));
    result = prime * result
            + ((fileName == null) ? 0 : fileName.hashCode());
    result = prime * result
            + ((interpreter == null) ? 0 : interpreter.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + reviewScore;
    result = prime * result + reviews;
    result = prime * result + ((title == null) ? 0 : title.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + yearReleased;
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Song other = (Song) obj;
    if (album == null) {
        if (other.album != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!album.equals(other.album))
        return false;
    if (author == null) {
        if (other.author != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!author.equals(other.author))
        return false;
    if (Double.doubleToLongBits(average) != Double
            .doubleToLongBits(other.average))
        return false;
    if (fileName == null) {
        if (other.fileName != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!fileName.equals(other.fileName))
        return false;
    if (interpreter == null) {
        if (other.interpreter != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!interpreter.equals(other.interpreter))
        return false;
    if (reviewScore != other.reviewScore)
        return false;
    if (reviews != other.reviews)
        return false;
    if (title == null) {
        if (other.title != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!title.equals(other.title))
        return false;
    if (yearReleased != other.yearReleased)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

you also seem to have a problem with the counter not incrementing properly, but I'm not going to do all of you homework for you! ;)

edit:
Woah!
You're also missing something like

```
       songTest[i] = song;
```

to add the checked song to your array.

also, to make sure your first song gets put in I added:

```
if(i==0){
        songTest[i] = x;
}
```

before your check.
The i is and int I added by changing your first for loop back to the old fashioned version, and I renamed your inner for loop to j.
Now it works.
try putting in something like:

```
System.out.println("i: " + i + " j: " + j + " count: " + count);
```

to see what's going on with your counters

You also exit after finding a duplicate. Is this the behavior you want? Or would it be better to notify the user, and continue inputting song data.

Comment: _and adding the hashCode() solved the problem_ Whenever you overriding `equals` you should override `hashCode` too. 
http://modprobe.wordpress.com/2010/09/07/equals-method/

Answer (score 1):

When I run this, I get a null pointer exception on this line

`if(songTest[i].equals(x)){`

It looks like you're not actually putting the song object (x) into the array.

Comment: I agree. It seems you are looping through an empty array. Perhaps the enhanced for loop is not the best option to loop through the array. Instead do for(int i=0;i<songTest.lenght;i++) in the loop and when you compare the equals, just add the condition songTest[i]!=null &&... Lastly, if the song is not found in the array, say songTest[i]=x; Ah! and also fix your equals method to use the String .equals method instead of ==